# Why the browser has a beforeunload event even though I do not use it in my codes?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a function to help the user scroll up to the top of the page like this:

```
function toTheTop(){
        document.getElementByID('topUpBtn').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            scrollTo( { top: document.querySelector('h1').getBoundingClientRect().top,
        behavior: 'smooth'})
    });
}

export {
    toTheTop
}
```

I am using Webpack for code organization. I called `toTheTop` function in an entry point as below:

```
import { toTheTop } from './js/TopUpButton.js';

if(document.readyState !== 'loading') {
    console.log('document is already ready');
    toTheTop();
} 
else{
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
        console.log('document was not ready'),
        toTheTop();
    });
}

export {
    toTheTop
}
```

I have tested this function without Webpack and it worked. However, when using with Webpack, it didn't. Inspect the console for the button I only see:

```
DOMContentloaded
click
```

But with Webpack setup, I see a weird line named `beforeunload` in order like this:

```
beforunload
click
```

open this line I saw:

```
self.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {
  status.isUnloading = true;
});
```

I did not implement this code at all. I looked for the use of `beforeunload` - this is only used if we want to prompt something for the user before leaving a page.

My questions are: Why do I have the `beforeunload` event-handler in my code? Does this relate to my Webpack setup? And how can I solve my problem?

I tried to figure it out for several days, but still can't handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it. Fortunately there is nothing wrong with my code. The function did not work because css elements conflicting with each other on different pages. It was hard to find but thank you guys. Posting a question helps me think it twice.